# Unique Code in a URL to Get Datas from Mysql in a laravel site

Tags: mysql, laravel, security

I have a laravel site and i have a mysql table with, among other columns, a column with a Md5 unique code.

Then I create a Get request with parameter id = Md5 that reload in a form web the others datas specific for that Md5 number.

It could be considered a site secure about these informations, even if this site has no login and password?

Or there is another method to implement a secure page for datas without login and pass

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

@Marco, for the overall "Is my site secure?" question, theres not any method/tech that ensure you 100% security, so probably the question should be "Is this site secure enough, based on its usage scenario? Which risks are we able to take in?"

Md5 hashes can be easily cracked by bruteforce, so a possible attack to your site could involve using a md5 dictionary attack to exfiltrate all possible data.

I'd think about other non-static(without user-password pairs) authentication methods as :

- Challenge response
- One-time passwords based on previous passwords
- One-time passwords based on time

Of course, all of the above are subject to resources avaliable to your organization, and again, your current site usage context.

Comment: with this "open to web" form there are name,surname field among other fields to compile. If i add a password field required sent with all the other fields by the user, then i can considere as login and pass to enter the site web ?

Comment: Or better i create a simple Register form no?

Comment: As you said, data you are referring to looks a lot like a register form (personal data). If you want the same user to retrieve his information without a password or md5 hash, probably you could use a challenge question from his own data, sort of "¿Whats the 3 last letters of your surname?" kind, still this is a very "fluffy" measure that will need other stuff for it to be safe from common attack vectors. I'd recommend you again to check proven authentication methods like the ones I listed in the answer.